# Paste contents to TextBox in ANSI Format

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, copy-paste, ansi

How can I make the textbox contents to ANSI format when paste in C#?

Comment: You need to say what programming language you're using, and with which GUI toolkit, on which operating systems.

Comment: Sorry Richie, I am using WPF & C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET uses Unicode for strings everywhere internally, including for the forms controls.  So I think you're real question is, given a byte-array, how do I convert that byte-array into Unicode using a desired source encoding ("ANSI" of some flavor)?

System.Text.Encoding has useful classes here.

Answer (score 0):

Try convert the Unicode to Ansi using FormatProvider. Maybe can is a solution?